# How do I assign a range of numbers to an if statement in C#?

Tags: c#

I want an if statement to activate over a certain range of number values and it's not working. Currently coding:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Minute == 20 - 39)
            lblMA2.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        else
            lblMA2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

The current time as of posting is within that range, and my label is staying gray. The same code works when I plug in an exact value. It'll turn blue as the minute hits, then gray as it passes. I plug in the range, and nothing.

Can anyone help me make it work without having to type in an extra 36 lines of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a number falls within a particular range, use `&&` on two conditions - the less than and the greater than, like this:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Minute >= 20 && DateTime.Now.Minute <= 39) {
    ...
}
```

`&&` means "AND". The composite condition evaluates to `true` when the left side evaluates to `true`, and then the right side also evaluates to `true`. The right side is evaluated only when the left side is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `if (Enumerable.Range(20, 19).Contains(DateTime.Now.Minute))`

Right now you're comparing `DateTime.Now.Minute` with `20 - 39` which is `-19`.

My solution creates a collection that contains the values from 20 to 39 and checks if the current minute is inside this collection.

Or you can just check if the minute is more than 20 and below 39 (which should be preferred, see the explanation by Konrad in the comments).

Comment: Wrong - it should be `Enumerable.Range(20, 19)`. The second parameter is `count`! See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx

Comment: I get caught by that every second time ;) By the way, I wouldn't recommend that method for very big rangesets, say millions. `Enumerable.Range` creates an actual sequence of consecutive numbers. It's deferred execution, but if you were checking whether `foo` falls in between -1000000 and 1000000, you might want to avoid making so many comparisons... For the needs of OP (where we know the upper bound won't be greater than 60) it's perfectly fine however

Comment: I definitely agree that simply checking the bounds is a lot more appropriate, I'll leave it up though as an alternative solution.

Comment: It's good, just not for big ranges. By the way, Google's Guava (their collections library for Java) has this nice `RangeSet` class which is designed specifically for these use cases. See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html 


It's a pity that noone has ported Guava (or the relevant bits - a lot of it is redundant in C#) to .NET.

Comment: @KonradMorawski I'm not that familiar with Guava, which parts and features do you think would be worth porting?

Comment: I don't know it inside out myself, and a lot of Guava is already provided by LINQ and/or lambdas in the .NET world (or other language constructs such as `Nullable`, implemented under the name `Optional` in Guava). Still, Guava brings along a number of neat features such as RangeSet, Preconditions, HashCode (it allows you to create your own clean `GetHashCode` implementation without all this `unchecked` / `... * 397) ^ ` stuff that ReSharper generates for you), ForwardingList etc.